# Does the Monty Hall problem occur on this situation?

Tags: probability, monty-hall

Lets say, I have the following situation:

> I know, that an alarm will go on on a certain day. It will go on on any day from Monday to Sunday.

On the week before, I know that the possibility is equal (1/7).

My question:
When it's Wednesday, two days have passed. Is the possibility for the alarm getting on still 1/7 or is it changed? And why or why not? I think the possibility didn't change, because it seems like to be like the monty hall problem.

Comment: And what if you are on sunday and haven't heard an alarm yet?

Comment: Oh I didn't think about that. Does that mean, the possibility is 0%? But it has to go on any of these days...

Comment: If it has to go on one of these days and on the days before sunday did not then the probability that it will go on on sunday is $1$.

Comment: There is some similarly to the Unexpected Hanging Paradox.  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unexpected_hanging_paradox

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a Monty Hall situation, since the events of the first two days were *not* guaranteed to turn out that way – in the original Monty Hall the host-opened door is guaranteed to have a zonk. There is also no initial choice of which day is the special one (will have the alarm go off then), something which happens in Monty Hall with the initial choice of door by the player.

Accordingly, the probability that the alarm goes off on Wednesday *given* that the first two days had no alarm is raised to $\frac15$. Formally:
$$P(\text{alarm goes on Wednesday}|\text{alarm doesn't go off on Monday or Tuesday})=\frac{1/7}{5/7}=\frac15$$